# why does cinnamon desktop installation install Unity and Gnome packages?

Tags: xubuntu, cinnamon

I recently installed Cinnamon Desktop package but when i rebooted then at the login screen, i saw apart from Cinnamon, there was Unity and Gnome also present whereas i only installed cinnamon.

Why is this?

I am installing it on top of Xubuntu, are the extra packages going to conflict with XFCE apps when i'll boot back into Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cinammon desktop has something known as **package dependencies**, most of which are fulfilled by the `ubuntu-desktop` (Unity) and `gnome-shell` (GNOME shell) packages.

Rater than define every single package dependency, Cinammon uses the meta package ubuntu-desktop.

As for Xubuntu, it shouldn't. I've had KDE, LXDE, XFCE, Unity and gnome-shell all installed on the same machine with no problems.

Comment: hmm..ok though its weird to see Unity and Gnome option visible at the login screen. Wish the developers find some way of 'hiding' them.

Comment: @Subeh That'd be a perfect question to ask on this site - I don't think it has been asked yet.

Comment: @fossfreedom I am on Xubuntu so not using Lightdm. Can I ask the question now :-)

Comment: ... oops my bad - yep as the question! xdm is the login manager?